# Saving a nested array in native storage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am saving a address book to [storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage). the interface looks like:

```js
interface AddressBook {
  a?: Contact[];
  b?: Contact[]
 // ...
}
```

the implementation I am using is:

```js
    try {
      const entries = this.addressBook.entries(); //<-- correct entries
      await this.contactStorage.set('contacts', Array.from(entries));
      const store: AddressBook = await this.contactStorage.get('contacts');
      console.log('store', store); //<-- shows an array of only one object
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('e-->', error);
    }
```

console.log on store shows:

```
(3) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
    0: (2) ["M", Array(1)]
    1: (2) ["P", Array(1)]
    2: (2) ["Z", Array(1)]
    length: 3
```

`"M"` should have a two objects inside the array but when saving it decided to delete one of the objects.

any help would be fantastic

edit: Here is the console of `const entries`:

```
MapIterator {"M" => Array(1), "P" => Array(1), "Z" => Array(1)}
__proto__: Map Iterator
[[IteratorHasMore]]: true
[[IteratorIndex]]: 0
[[IteratorKind]]: "entries"
[[Entries]]: Array(3)
0: {"M" => Array(2)} //<-- both objects are there
1: {"P" => Array(1)}
2: {"Z" => Array(1)}
```

Comment: Can you log `entries` before storing it in storage?

Comment: try `JSON.stringify()` before storing  and `JSON.parse()` before retrieving the value

Comment: @yashpatelyk yea I'll update with the log of entries.

Comment: @JoelJoseph I've tried the `stringify()` but it only stringify's one object of the array

Comment: @Ctfrancia you should stringify on save (set)

Answer (score 0):

In our project we are using this:

https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

you can define what to hide what to @expose and then you can tranform the stringify json to class and back again

Comment: Thanks for that. This isn't exactly my problem. It's more of an issue that if I save an array of two objects, then the most last one in the array is saved ontop of the other items.

Comment: @Ctfrancia what is behind contactStorage?

Comment: I am using [ionic/storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage) which is an abstraction ontop of SQLite

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem and it was editing my code from this:

```js
  private async _createAddressBook(contactsArr: Contact[] = contacts): Promise<void> {
    this._sortedArray = await contactsArr.sort(this._compare);
    this._sortedArray.forEach(async (record: Contact): Promise<void> => {
      const char = this._replaceFirstCharAccentMark(record.lastNames[0].toUpperCase());
      if (this.addressBook.has(char)) {
        const bucket: Contact[] = this.addressBook.get(char) as Contact[];
        const sortedBucket: Contact[] = bucket.concat(record).sort(this._compare);
        this.addressBook.set(char, sortedBucket);
      } else {
        this.addressBook.set(char, [record]);
      }
    });
  }
```

to this:

```js
  private _createAddressBook(contactsArr: Contact[] = contacts): void {
    this._sortedArray = await contactsArr.sort(this._compare);
    this._sortedArray.forEach((record: Contact): void => {
      const char = this._replaceFirstCharAccentMark(record.lastNames[0].toUpperCase());
      console.log('char', char);
      if (this.addressBook.has(char)) {
        const bucket: Contact[] = this.addressBook.get(char) as Contact[];
        const sortedBucket: Contact[] = bucket.concat(record).sort(this._compare);
        this.addressBook.set(char, sortedBucket);
      } else {
        this.addressBook.set(char, [record]);
      }
    });
  }
```

I don't know why the async/await was messing it up though. Because as the more and more contacts I get the longer and longer the sort will take. So why would blocking it till it's finished sorting create these side effects